# Code First Entity Framework. Eager loading, validating then saving causing error

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

My setup is that I have a basket which contains items.  An item is made up of a product and a size.  Products have a many to many relationship with sizes so that I can verify that a given size is valid for a given product.   I would like to be able to add an item to the basket, perform some validation and save to the database.

I have created a demo program to demonstrate the problem I am having.  When the program runs there is already a basket saved to the database (see the DBInitializer).  It has one item which is a large foo.  In the program you can see that I load the basket, load a  small size and a bar product. I add the large bar to the basket.  The basket does some internal validation and I save to the database.  This works without error.

The problem comes when I try to add a product that already exists in the database with a different size.  Hence if we try to add a large bar to the basket and save we get a null reference exception.  This is not the behaviour I would like because a basket which contains 2 items, a large foo and a small foo, is perfectly valid.

I'm pretty sure the problem is to do with the fact that we have already loaded foo in the basket through eager loading.  I've tried commenting out the eager loading for the basketitems and this works.  However if possible I would like a solution which keeps the eager loading.

Notes: I have added an extra method to my dbcontext class which is int SaveChanges(bool excludeReferenceData).  This stops extra product and size records being saved back to the database.  I've made all my constructors, getters and setters public to make it easier to replicate my problem.  My demo code was created on a console app targeting .net framework 4.5.2.  The version of Entity framework is 6.2.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using static Demo.Constants;

namespace Demo
{
    public static class Constants
    {
        public static int BasketId => 1;
        public static int SmallId => 1;
        public static int LargeId => 2;       
        public static int FooId => 1;
        public static int BarId => 2;
    }  

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            using (var context = new AppContext())
            {
                var customerBasket = context.Baskets
                    .Include(b => b.Items.Select(cbi => cbi.Product))
                    .Include(b => b.Items.Select(cbi => cbi.Size))
                .SingleOrDefault(b => b.Id == BasketId);

                var size = context.Sizes.AsNoTracking()
                         .SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id == SmallId);    
                context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
                var product = context
                    .Products
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .Include(p => p.Sizes)
                    .SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == BarId);  
                     //changing BarId to FooId in the above line results in 
                     //null reference exception when savechanges is called.

                customerBasket.AddItem(product, size);
                context.SaveChanges(excludeReferenceData: true);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
         }
    }   

    public class Basket
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

        public Basket()
        {
            Items = new Collection<Item>();
        }

        public void AddItem(Product product, Size size)
        {
            if (itemAlreadyExists(product, size))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("item already in basket");
            }

            var newBasketItem = Item.Create(
              this,
              product,
              size);

            Items.Add(newBasketItem);    
        }

        private bool itemAlreadyExists(Product product, Size size)
        {
            return Items.Any(a => a.ProductId == product.Id && a.SizeId == size.Id);
        }
    }    

    public class Item
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public int BasketId { get; set; }

        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }

        public virtual Size Size { get; set; }
        public int SizeId { get; set; }

        public Item()
        {

        }

        public string getDescription()
        {
            return $"{Product.Name} - {Size.Name}";
        }    

        internal static Item Create(Basket basket
            , Product product,
            Size size)
        {
            Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();

            if (!product.HasSize(size))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("product does not come in size");
            }

            var basketItem = new Item
            {
                Id = id,
                BasketId = basket.Id,
                Product = product,
                ProductId = product.Id,
                Size = size,
                SizeId = size.Id
            };
            return basketItem;
        }
    }

    public class Product : IReferenceObject
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get;  set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ProductSize> Sizes { get;  set; }

        public Product()
        {
            Sizes = new Collection<ProductSize>();
        }

        public bool HasSize(Size size)
        {
            return Sizes.Any(s => s.SizeId == size.Id);
        }
    }

    public class ProductSize : IReferenceObject
    {
        public int SizeId { get;  set; }
        public virtual Size Size { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
    }    

    public class Size : IReferenceObject
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class AppContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Basket> Baskets { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Size> Sizes { get; set; }          

        public AppContext()
           : base("name=DefaultConnection")
        {    
            Database.SetInitializer(new DBInitializer());
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Basket>()
            .HasMany(c => c.Items)
            .WithRequired()
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.BasketId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
            .Property(c => c.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
            .HasKey(c => new { c.Id, c.BasketId });

            modelBuilder.Entity<ProductSize>()
                .HasKey(c => new { c.ProductId, c.SizeId });
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        }

        public int SaveChanges(bool excludeReferenceData)
        {
            if(excludeReferenceData)
            {
                var referenceEntries = 
                     ChangeTracker.Entries<IReferenceObject>()
                    .Where(e => e.State != EntityState.Unchanged 
                           && e.State != EntityState.Detached);

                foreach (var entry in referenceEntries)
                {
                   entry.State = EntityState.Detached;
                }
            }

            return SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public interface IReferenceObject
    {
    }

    public class DBInitializer: DropCreateDatabaseAlways<AppContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(AppContext context)
        {

            context.Sizes.Add(new Size { Id = LargeId, Name = "Large" });
            context.Sizes.Add(new Size { Id = SmallId, Name = "Small" });            

            context.Products.Add(
                new Product
                {
                    Id = FooId,
                    Name = "Foo",
                    Sizes = new Collection<ProductSize>()
                    {
                        new ProductSize{ProductId = FooId, SizeId = LargeId},
                        new ProductSize{ProductId = FooId, SizeId =SmallId}
                    }
                });

            context.Products.Add(new Product { Id = BarId, Name = "Bar",
                Sizes = new Collection<ProductSize>()
                    {
                        new ProductSize{ProductId = BarId, SizeId = SmallId}                        
                    }
            });

            context.Baskets.Add(new Basket
            {
                Id = BasketId,
                Items = new Collection<Item>()
                {
                    new Item
                    {
                        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        BasketId =BasketId,
                        ProductId = FooId,
                        SizeId = LargeId
                    }
                }
            });    
            base.Seed(context);
        }
    } 
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use AsNoTracking, this tells EF to not include the objects being loaded into the DbContext ChangeTracker.  You normally want to do this when you load data to be returned and know you aren't going to want to save it back at that point.  Thus, I think you just need to get rid of AsNoTracking on all of your calls and it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help, much appreciated.